# tabhost with icons

Tags: android, view, android-tabhost

I wanted to add icons to my tabview, but it dont work and look a bit ... bad. (Pic: [click me](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2843058/demo_tabs.png)). I used the from android shiped photoshop templates to design the icons. Size is 48x48. 
 
 This is the state list xml (list.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_list_selected"
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- unselected state (default) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_list_unselected" />
</selector>
```

The tabhost:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("list").setIndicator("Stations"
              ,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.list))
              .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

The icon is in the folder "drawable-v5" (I dont use alway only drawable with the greatest icon / resource size. That means, no drawable-mdpi-v5 and drawable-hdpi-v5 and so on)

Can anyone help me, why my tabhost looks so ugly? I cant find the problem ... 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Solved it. Renamed folder to drawable-hdpi-v5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Renamed folder to drawable-hdpi-v5